# Evaluate Excel cell values and print the result in the same row one column to the right

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to figure out how to read data in a column in Excel, and print the result one column to the right, in the Excel worksheet (not in the Python console).  Below is the code that I'm testing.  It seems to work, but it just displays the results in the console, and I really want to write the results to the adjacent cell (column B) in Excel.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for row in ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        if isinstance(cell.value, str):
            print('string')
        elif isinstance(cell.value, int):
            print('integer')
        elif isinstance(cell.value, float):
            print('float')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy:

If it's fixed that you want to write into column B:

```
for rowno,row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)),start=1):
    for cell in row:
        if isinstance(cell.value, str):
            print('string')
            ws.cell(row=rowno,column=2).value = str("string")
        elif isinstance(cell.value, int):
            print('integer')
            ws.cell(row=rowno,column=2).value = str("integer")
        elif isinstance(cell.value, float):
            print('float')
            ws.cell(row=rowno,column=2).value = str("float")
wb.save('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx')
```

For more generic answer:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string

for rowno,row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)),start=1):
    for cell in row:
        if isinstance(cell.value, str):
            xy = coordinate_from_string(cell.coordinate)
            colno = column_index_from_string[0]
            ws.cell(row=rowno, column=colno+1).value = str("string")
        elif isinstance(cell.value, int):
            xy = coordinate_from_string(cell.coordinate)
            colno = column_index_from_string[0]
            ws.cell(row=rowno, column=colno+1).value = str("string")
        elif isinstance(cell.value, float):
            xy = coordinate_from_string(cell.coordinate)
            colno = column_index_from_string[0]
            ws.cell(row=rowno, column=colno+1).value = str("string")
wb.save('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx')
```

Comment: There is no need ever to use `ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `cell.offset(column=1)` to get the next cell.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that.  I tried a few ideas, but I couldn't write the results to the adjacent cell.  Also, I just tested your code and I couldn't get it to write ot the adjacent cell.

Comment: @ReKx, that solves the problem in Python, but it doesn't write the results to Excel.  That's what I wanted to do.  Maybe the way to do this is to import the data from Excel into Python, do the work in Python, and then write everything back to Excel.  I'll try to do that, and post back with my final results.

Comment: After doing all the writing just use wb.save(‘you/dir/path/abcde.xlsx’)